# iOS imageview jpeg error, echo from php server corrupt

Tags: php, ios, nsurlconnection, jpeg

I have a base64 encoded imageview that i send to php, and when i echo it back it is corrupted when i try to turn it back into an imageview. My decoder works because when i decode it locally it works fine..So it must be corrupted once i send it to php. This is the Log Error Message:

```
   Jan  8 14:21:33 Vessel.local Topic[11039] <Error>: ImageIO: JPEG Corrupt JPEG data:214          extraneous bytes before marker 0x68  Jan  8 14:21:33 Vessel.local Topic[11039] <Error>: ImageIO: JPEG Unsupported marker type 0x68
```

Can someone tell me what that means and how i cant prevent the string from being corrupted once i send it to the server. I use a normal iOS post delegates and have no error, the only error is once i convert it to the imageview.

This is the code to encode the image to base64:

```
  NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(crop, 1.0);
    NSString *baseString = [imageData base64EncodedString];
    int original =[baseString length];
    NSLog(@"orignal String=%@",baseString);
    [self register:username.text withPass:password.text withEmail:email.text withQuote:quote.text withPic:baseString];
```

This is code i use to send the image to my php server:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/Topic/Mobile/auth/registration.php"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *param = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@&email=%@&quote=%@&pic=%@",user,password,email,quote,pic];
[request setHTTPBody:[param dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

This is code I use to turn the base64 string back into an image:

```
   -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

homeData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:nil error:nil];

NSString *decodeString = [[homeData objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"profile_pic" ];
//int returnNUM = [decodeString length];
NSLog(@"RETURN STRING=%@",decodeString);
NSData *data = [NSData dataFromBase64String:decodeString];
profilepic = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 4, 120, 120)];
profilepic.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(profilepic.bounds.size, NO, 1.0);
[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:profilepic.bounds cornerRadius:80.0] addClip];
[profilepic.image drawInRect:profilepic.bounds];
profilepic.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[self.view addSubview:profilepic];
```

}

The encoder and decoder work fine..some how the string is messed up when i post it to the web. I tried to echo it back as soon as i sent it to the php and it was still corrupted..so the moment it leaves the phone the content changes. PLEASE HELP OR PLEASE UPLOAD AND EXAMPLE OF HOW TO POST AN IMAGE AND NSSTRING PAREMETERS TOGETHER IN ONE POST

Comment: We need the code in order to help.

Comment: ok i will edit my answer

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you found any solution?

Comment: I figured out the solution..in order to fix it you have to use the post command in a form/data format with boundaries.if you try to send encoded data this way it gets corrupted everytime